# Grouping a Child after Sorting XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to group some data that I've already sorted by adding another group after the "Events" parent.

Here's my code where I already have the sorting function working, I am just wondering how to add another group under "Events" before it sorts. Any help is appreciated as I am very new to XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Games">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Game/Event[@type_id='1' and @team_id='8']">
                <xsl:sort select="event_id" order="ascending" data-type="number"  />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share your input/source on which you need to group data ? Also you can share what output is required.

Comment: Currently, with my original XSLT, the data comes in formatted as Games->Event->info. I want to be able to format it where Event is the child of a brand new group, while keeping my current transformation intact. Essentially, I want the tree to be Games->New Grp->Event->info.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is quite easy if you can use **XSLT 2.0**.

Assume that your input is something like below:

```
<Games>
  <Game id="g1">
    <Event event_id="34" xx="1">Abcd 1</Event>
    <Event event_id="33" xx="1">Abcd 2</Event>
    <Event event_id="32" xx="2">Abcd 3</Event>
    <Event event_id="31" xx="2">Abcd 4</Event>
  </Game>
  <Game id="g2">
    <Event event_id="24" xx="1">Efgh 1</Event>
    <Event event_id="23" xx="1">Efgh 2</Event>
    <Event event_id="22" xx="2">Efgh 3</Event>
    <Event event_id="21" xx="2">Efgh 4</Event>
  </Game>
  <Game id="g3">
    <Event event_id="14" xx="1">Ijkl 1</Event>
    <Event event_id="13" xx="1">Ijkl 2</Event>
    <Event event_id="12" xx="2">Ijkl 3</Event>
    <Event event_id="11" xx="2">Ijkl 4</Event>
  </Game>
</Games>
```

Assume also that you want e.g. to group events on `xx` attribute.

Then you can use `xsl:for-each-group`. `select` attribute specifies
source objects to group (`Game/Event`). `group-by` attribute specifies
the method of grouping, this time `by @xx` (there are 3 other methods).

An example script can be like below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="Games">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Game/Event" group-by="@xx">
        <Group><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
          <xsl:sort select="@event_id" order="ascending" data-type="number"  />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To simplify the task, I dropped the predicate concerning *type_id* and `team_id`.
For demonstration purposes I added an extra output element, as a head of each group.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbSW

If you have to use **XSLT 1.0** search the Web for *Muenchian grouping*.
This is to some extent more difficult task, but still possible.
There are numerous examples, even on *StackOverflow*.